# vspace not working after linebreak

Tags: spacing

For this minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Hallo \\
How \\
Are \\
\vspace{15cm}You?
\end{document}
```

There is no vertical space created between the word **Are** and **You**. How can I add vertical space between them? Using \vspace* did not work either.

Comment: Just leave an empty line after `Are` and remove the `\\\`

Comment: You might want to use ``\\[15cm]``, but you're misusing the tool anyway. There is ***very rarely*** need for ``\\`` in normal text.

Comment: You could also use `\par` instead of `\\\` after "Are".

Comment: @egreg actually I tried '\vspace[15cm]You?' and it seemed to work, and I have no idea why.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`\vspace` if used mid paragraph, as here, stores the vertical space in a special place (a vadjust node) which is then inserted after the paragraph has been broken into lines, after the line on which the space is added. in your example the `\vspace` is added in the last line of the paragraph so the space comes after the paragraph. Compare

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent
Hallo \\
How \\
Are \\
You?

xxxxx

\noindent
Hallo \\
How \\
Are \\
\vspace{15cm}You?

xxxxx
\end{document}
```

[image]

to add a space at the linebreak you should use

```
\\[3cm]
```

but it is almost always wrong to use `\\` at all apart from its use in tables.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, I write

```
a lot of stuff I write\\
a new line\\
\vspace{15cm} \ \\     % the \ is necessary, otherwise you will get a no-line-to-end-error.
You
```

`\vspace` and `\hspace` are very sensitive to new lines (\\) and new paragraphs (double linefeed). Changing vspace to `\vspace*` is also always a good first try.

There will be people saying, that this code isn't beautiful. Remember: All codes are beautiful.

Comment: ugly code does exist http://uglycode.com/

Comment: this is completely wrong