# LaTeX-Beamer: How to have two columns and center pictures in one of them

Tags: beamer

Thx to this life-saving forum, I was able to create a slide in LaTeX-Beamer that looks almost as I want it to:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{MyTitle}
            \begin{columns}[T]
                \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                    \begin{block}{}
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item Item1
                            \item Item2
                            \item Item3
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{block}
                \end{column}
                \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                        \begin{block}{}
                            \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth {imgs/Image1.jpg}
                            \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{imgs/Image2.jpg}
                        \end{block}
                \end{column}
            \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Now, I want the two images in the right column to be centered. They are left-aligned. Furthermore I want to have a little vertical space between them. I have tried `addvspace{2pt}`, `vspace*{2pt}` but non of these seem to work.

Comment: Your code is not compileable !

Comment: hmm... ok. Did you add your own images?

Comment: It is up to you to make sure that users can help you by giving a fully compileable code. By putting example images: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/454454/138900

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beamer uses TeX's normal rules to position text and graphics. So, for example, you can use a `center` environment for your images. As for the vertical space, make sure you end the paragraph first with e.g. a blank line (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301954/172926) for info).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{MyTitle}
            \begin{columns}[T]
                \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                    \begin{block}{}
                        \begin{itemize}
                            \item Item1
                            \item Item2
                            \item Item3
                        \end{itemize}
                    \end{block}
                \end{column}
                \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
                        \begin{block}{}
                        \begin{center}
                            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}

                            \vspace{1cm}
                            \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-b}
                        \end{center}
                        \end{block}
                \end{column}
            \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: thx a lot, Pippip19 ! ... do you know how to add captions to these figures? It seems captions need for example a minipage. But I don't want to have so many nested-structures, I already have columns and boxes!

Comment: You can place each image in a `figure` environment and then use `\caption{}` in the normal way. I would recommend loading the `caption` package. If you want the figures to be numbered, put `\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]{}` in your preamble.

Comment: yeah I managed, thx a lot!